# How do I set values of CrossAxisAlignment?

Tags: dart, alignment, flutter

I want to set values(as a list) of positions of Column class in flutter. Usually setting something like CrossAxisAlignment.center sets positions of all children as center. But there is also a parameter called 'values' of const List which sets values of children in a list accordingly but it gives me error 'Error: setter values not found' I even tried List.values but it gives same error. What would be the correct way to define values of CrossAxisAlignment? 
Here is the class reference: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html

Here is the whole code lib/main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(SoundRecorder());
}

class SoundRecorder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
               Tab(text: 'Record'),
            Tab(text: 'Saved Recordings'),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [ 


                new Column(               
          crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.values = [CrossAxisAlignment.center, CrossAxisAlignment.center],
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [ new Text("this is it"),
          new FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 0.0,
          child: new Icon(Icons.check),
          backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
          onPressed: (){}
        )]
            ),
                  new Center(child:  new FloatingActionButton(
               elevation: 0.0,
             child: new Icon(Icons.check),
            backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
          onPressed: (){}
        )
        )

        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`values` is a unique value present in all enums.
It is the list of all potential enum values.

Which means `CrossAxisAlignment.values` is not made to be assignable to `Column.crossAxisAlignment`.

Instead, it can be used when you need to iterate over all the potential types to do some kind of operation.

Comment: Can you please give an example what should I put instead of `crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.values = [CrossAxisAlignment.center, CrossAxisAlignment.center]`?

Comment: `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to set alignment of each child individually? Is there a way to do that? I dont wanna use the Positioned class because it may spoil the layout in some devices

Comment: No. Instead wrap each child individually into an `Align`

Comment: Got it. Thanks! :)